# Android Universal Image Loader URI from InputStream

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

i want to ask about UIL which the URI input from InputStream. Because my image source from ZIP and then i must extract it to show that image. Because the image is too big, i must use the UIL library, anybody know how to insert UIL from InputStream.

Comment: Pass absolute path of the image to show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do it similar to loading images from DB - [Can Universal image loader for android work with images from sqlite db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231489/can-universal-image-loader-for-android-work-with-images-from-sqlite-db)

Lets choose own scheme so our URIs will look like **"stream://..."**.

Then implement `ImageDownloader`. We should catch URIs with our scheme and return image stream.

```
public class StreamImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

    private static final String SCHEME_STREAM = "stream";
    private static final String STREAM_URI_PREFIX = SCHEME_STREAM + "://";

    public StreamImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        if (imageUri.startsWith(STREAM_URI_PREFIX)) {
            return (InputStream) extra;
        } else {
            return super.getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we set this `ImageDownloader into configuration:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    ...
    .imageDownloader(new StreamImageDownloader(context))
    .build();
```

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

And then we can do following to display image from DB:

```
ImageStream is = ...; // You have image stream
// You should generate some unique string ID for this stream
// Streams for the same images should have the same string ID
String imageId = "stream://" + is.hashCode();

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    ...
    .extraForDownloader(is)
    .build();

imageLoader.displayImage(imageId, imageView, options);
```

Comment: Hi @NOSTRA, Implementing your answer i faced this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654279/java-inputsream-hascode-is-different-each-time-even-when-the-request-is-same). Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Acceptable paths

```
String imageUri = "http://someurl.com/image.png"; // from Web
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```

Then show the image

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

from documentation: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader